# PHP and AJAX: cache RSS data

Tags: php, xml, caching, rss

Consider the following AJAX call to load RSS news data on click event:

```
 $(function() {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.msg_head').eq(0).click(function(){
                    $('.msg_body').eq(0).load('printSideNews.php');
                    $('.loadMessage').eq(2).hide();
                });
    });
});
```

`printSideNews.php` looks like this:

```
include ('newsFeed.php');
  function printNewsMenu($itemD){
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
            if($itemD==null)
            echo "An error has occured, please try again later";
            $article_title = $itemD[$i]->title;
            $article_link = $itemD[$i]->link;
            echo "<a href='".$article_link."' title='".$article_title."' target='_blank'>". $article_title. " </a></br>". PHP_EOL;
}
printNewsMenu($itemD);
```

The included `newsFeed.php` file lloks like:

```
$urlD = "someurl";
    $xmlD = simplexml_load_file($urlD);
    $itemD = $xmlD->channel->item;
```

I need to cache the `$itemD` or the `$xmlD` object - not sure which one. This should be cached for 1 hour then taken again from the url. Any help with code caching this mess will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your **question** and what have you tried so far to solve your problem? This isn't rent-a-coder-but-pay-0-for-help, so unless you clarify what you have tried and where you've failed - you're at the wrong place.

Comment: Do you have any kind of session state for the user ?

Comment: I won't build user functionality. The site will have only visitors. The idea is to have some folder for caching not to use Sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this function:

```
    <?php      
    function cacheObject($url,$name,$age = 86400)
      { 
        // directory in which to store cached files
        $cacheDir = "cache/";
        // cache filename constructed from MD5 hash of URL
        $filename = $cacheDir.$name;
        // default to fetch the file
        $cache = true;
        // but if the file exists, don't fetch if it is recent enough
        if (file_exists($filename))
        {
          $cache = (filemtime($filename) < (time()-$age));
        }
        // fetch the file if required
        if ($cache)
        {
          $xmlD = simplexml_load_file($url);
          $itemD = $xmlD->channel->item;
          file_put_contents($filename,serialize($itemD));
          // update timestamp to now
          touch($filename);
        }
        // return the cache filename
        return unserialize(file_get_contents($filename));
      }     


$urlD = "someurl";

$itemD = cacheObject($urlD,'cacheobject',3600);
```

Comment: At this time I'm using localhost with XAMPP server so URL's aren't necessary?

Comment: updated your code to an example, waht your **newsFeed.php** could look like, with 1 hour caching of your feed

Comment: Really helpful, now I'll try to implement it

Comment: My mistake - is it better idea to cache the item objects and how because parsing the xml files from the computer is kinda slow?

Comment: the parsing should not be a big problem on a webserver, so chaching the feed should be good.

Comment: Yeah you're right but I'm in interested in the best possible performance. +1 to all your posts. I'll be very glad if you give ideas about caching the items objects once the XML files are saved to the server.

Comment: updated my code to cache the item, its untested but should be working